# Sharing components between two react projects in same repo

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have two projects in the same repo that I'd like to be able to share components. Ideally, under the root folder, I'd like to have a separate folder for my first project, containing all node modules, ios files, etc, and a separate similar folder for my second project. Then I'd like to create a 'shared' folder on the same level, containing only the components I am sharing between the two. So ideally, all three of those folders will be at the same level, under the root folder. When trying to import a component from the 'shared' folder within my project, it first told me it needed a package.json. After I created that, it gives me the error "unable to resolve [folderName] as a folder: it contained a package, but its 'main' could not be resolved".

Has anyone had any experience with this? If I want my two projects to be able to access components within the shared folder, how should I go about structuring the folders?

Answer (score 0):

react-native look for `package.json` only if you import from a `folder`.

import from a file instead.

example:

```js
import { Button } from './shared/button/mybuttonjs';
```